# AWS IAM policy to update specific ECS cluster through AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

We're running a staging env in a separate ECS Fargate cluster. I'm trying to allow an external developers to update tasks and services in this cluster through the AWS Console.

I've created a policy that looks OK for me based on the documentation. Updates through the AWS cli work.

However the AWS Console requires a lot of other, only loosly related permissions. Is there a way to find out which permissions are required? I'm looking at CloudTrail logs but it takes 20 min until somethin shows up. Also I'd like to avoid giving unrelated permissions, even if they are read-only.

Comment: I think you can use AmazonECS_FullAccess managed policy, see this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs_managed_policies.html#AmazonECS_FullAccess

Comment: Good idea. Maybe I should start from there and try to limit stuff by resources.